# Running exe from command line with parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, command-line, scheduled-tasks, environment

I have created a WPF application which I would like to run from the command line, so I can schedule this command to be executed using Windows Task Scheduler.

For example, using a command line:

`start "App.exe" "ID=1"`

My questions is, how do I configure my WPF application to handle a call like this and is this the right syntax I should be using from making the call from the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a WPF application, you can access the command line by using the static members of the Environment class...

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
            if (args.Length == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No argument provided");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            string arg1 = args[1];  // your argument
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

This snippet shows how to do it.  Remember that the name of the assembly is always the first argument, so you are interested in args[1] and args[2] etc etc.

The Environment class also has another member: Environment.CommandLine which has the entire command line as a string.

For your second question, your syntax is fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. When I run command prompt and enter in the command: start "App.exe" "ID=1", I get the following error Windows cannot find "ID=1". Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again?

Comment: That's a question about the Start command and not WPF.  The Start command is a bit eccentric when it comes to double quotes so it thinks "App.exe" is the title and ID=1 is the executable.